# How to remove double html <strong> tag from string in C#

Tags: c#, html, regex, asp.net-mvc-3, search

I want to made search on my ASP.NET MVC 3 site, so for search I have to find matched patterns and in that words replace matched part with the same part in bold(I us efor that html `<strong>` tag).

So I have this in my controller

```
        string[] words=content.Split(' ');
        foreach (Thread thread in context.Threads)
        {
            foreach (string word in words)
            {
                if (thread.Title.ToLower().Contains(word.ToLower()))
                {
                    thread.Title=Regex.Replace(thread.Title,word,String.Format("<strong>{0}</strong>","$0"),RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                }
            }

         }
```

So, if I search `new thread a` It will find thread like this `New thrEAd`.

But in html it makes my string like that

```
<strong>New</strong> <strong>thrE<strong>A</strong>d</strong>
```

So I want to remove strong tag from a, because it makes a double-bold...
How can I do that?

And if you have interesting ways to do my search, I will glad to hear your suggestions too.

Comment: Sorry for the question but I need to understand this. So you have a list of words that if they match, they should be enclosed by <strong>. Is this the question?

Answer (score 1):

You could clean up your search words, by checking that none of them contains any of the others:

```
var cleanWords = words.Where(w => !words.Any(w2 => w2.Contains(w));
```

Comment: It's not a solution... What if I have "New a Thread"... It will not make bold "a", because "Thread" contains "a" ))

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IEnumerable<string> enumerableWords = content.Split(' ').Distinct();
string[] words = enumerableWords.ToArray();
foreach (Thread thread in context.Threads) {
    string result = thread.Title;
    foreach (string word in words) {
        result = Regex.Replace(result, String.Format(@"\b{0}\b", word), String.Format(@"<strong>{0}</strong>", word), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    }
    thread.Title = result;
}
```